# Using flows to return a list as a terminal operator

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

I have the following that returns a `Flow<List<Events>>`. But I want return the `List<Events>>` from the flow instead of Flow<List>

```
val events = eventDao.getEventsFromTimeStamp(startTimeStamp, endTimeStamp)
                .map { listOfEventEntity ->
                    listOfEventEntity.map { eventEntity ->
                        eventEntity.toEvent()
                    }
                }
```

I have tried using the following operators

```
val listOfEvents = events.single()
val listOfEvent = events.toList().flatten()
```

This is my eventDao that return a flow

```
fun getEventsFromTimeStamp(startTimeStamp: Long, endTimeStamp: Long): Flow<List<EventEntity>>
```

Comment: Do you need to take only the first list from the flow and return it? (pretty much your first solution). Or take all lists and concatenate them? (your second solution, although it can be done better). Why/how your proposed solutions are not sufficient?

Comment: I would use `first()` instead of `single()` if you don't care about the possibility of the flow containing more than one item. Otherwise, it will crash. If this is a flow from Room, it definitely has more than one item--it has infinite items, and `single()` will hang waiting for the second item before crashing when that second item arrives. And your second attempt will hang forever if the flow is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

If both `single()` and `toList().flatten()` aren't working for you then the `Flow` is not emitting any items.

`single()` should results in:

- The **single** item of the `Flow`
- `NoSuchElementException` for empty flow
- `IllegalStateException` for flow that contains more than one element.
- Or never returns a value for *infinite* stream that never emits a value.

This last case is possible if for example you're streaming a query from Android Room, SqlDelight or Kafka but the stream remains empty forever since the table remains empty or no events are published to Kafka.

`toList().flatten()` should result in:

- The flattened `List` of **all** `List` values in the `Flow`.
- Hangs forever if streaming from Room, SqlDelight, Kafka, etc. Anything that provides an *infinite* stream.

To make an *infinite* stream *finite* you can use the `take` operator.

Let's take an example:

```kotlin
val infinite: Flow<List<Int>> =
  flow {
    while(true) {
      emit(listOf(1, 2, 3))
    }
  }

val res: List<Int> =
  infinite
    .take(3)
    .toList()
    .flatten() // listOf(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

In case that the stream is *infinite* but never emits a value, this will hang. Similar to for `single`. This *could* be fixed using a *timeout* to prevent it hanging forever. It's not an ideal situation, since it will always take the timeout duration to get a result, but at least it will terminate.

```kotlin
val empty: Flow<List<Int>> =
  callbackFlow {
     // await forever, never terminate or emit
    awaitClose { }
  }

val res =
  withTimeoutOrNull(1.seconds) {
   empty
     .take(3)
     .toList().flatten() // same applies for single
  } ?: emptyList() // emptyList()
```